# BTC-e international wire transfer in USD from Russia

Tags: btce, wire-transfers

I tried to make a wire transfer in USD, but the bank refused. Their reason was that the supporting documents should be provided for such transaction.
Payment details which BTC-E provides do not contain both the basis and the reason of the payment (which should be specified too). As far as I know any wire transfer to a company from a person should be supported with documents.
Has anyone made a successful wire transfer from Russia with those details?

Answer (score 1):

I contacted another bank and was reassured that any wire transfer from a Russian resident to any person or company could be made without supporting documents if it is under 5000 USD or equivalent.
As for the reason of the payment it could be filled with something like "transfer of personal funds"

Edit: However, the so called currency control, which is an inner bank department, demands documents anyway. Normally it's a customer agreement which could be simply downloaded from the website and some kind of a document showing that you're an account holder.